# If input.val() is in Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement

I need to check if the value of the radio:checked or the user input is equal to a radio group. There are several input radio groups. I store each radio group in array.

I am trying to get the user input and checking if it exist in array of the radio group please help.

```js
var userInput = $(this).val();
  radioGroupOne = $(value).find('input[name="optionOne"]').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get().join(", "),
  radioGroupTwo = $(value).find('input[name="optionTwo"]').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get().join(", ");



  if ($.inArray(userInput, radioGroupOne) >= 0) {
    alert(userInput + 'is in group one');
  }
  
  if ($.inArray(userInput, radioGroupTwo) >= 0) {
    alert(userInput + 'is in group Two');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<br>
<label class="title">Group one</label>
<fieldset class="options-block">
  <input type="radio" name="optionOne" value="red">
  <label>Red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionOne" value="blue">
  <label>Blue</label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionOne" value="green">
  <label>Green</label>
</fieldset>
<br>
<label class="title">Group two</label>
<fieldset class="options-block">
  <input type="radio" name="optionTwo" value="banana">
  <label>banana</label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionTwo" value="grape">
  <label>grape</label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionTwo" value="lemon">
  <label>lemon</label>
</fieldset>

<br>
```

Comment: if i click the Red radio it would show an alert Radio group one? is this your expected result?

Comment: Yes @vsogrimen that's correct

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a `class` in each `option` of the group and monitor the `change event`.

**OR**

use the name of the `input` `$('input[name="optionOne" ]').change()` as suggested by `@OmarYafer`

**Try this.**

```js
/*
$('.g1').change(function () {
    alert('Group One');
})

$('.g2').change(function () {
    alert('Group Two');
})
*/

//@OmarYafer's solution:

$('input[name="optionOne" ]').change(function () {
    alert('Group One');
})

$('input[name="optionTwo" ]').change(function () {
    alert('Group Two');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<br>
<label class="title">Group one</label>
<fieldset class="options-block">
  <input class="g1" type="radio" name="optionOne" value="red">
  <label>Red</label>
  <input class="g1" type="radio" name="optionOne" value="blue">
  <label>Blue</label>
  <input class="g1" type="radio" name="optionOne" value="green">
  <label>Green</label>
</fieldset>
<br>
<label class="title">Group two</label>
<fieldset class="options-block">
  <input class="g2" type="radio" name="optionTwo" value="banana">
  <label>banana</label>
  <input class="g2" type="radio" name="optionTwo" value="grape">
  <label>grape</label>
  <input class="g2" type="radio" name="optionTwo" value="lemon">
  <label>lemon</label>
</fieldset>

<br>
```

I hope this has given you some idea.

~vsogrimen

Comment: You don´t actually need to add a class. You can select the first radio group with $('input[name="optionOne"]') instead of $('.g1')

Comment: @OmarYafer yeah, nice.... Thanks for the suggestion, I'll be editing my answer :)

Comment: Actually your answer is great as is, but the jQuery ( "[attributeFilter1][attributeFilter2][attributeFilterN]" ) selection style can very handy when you need to select things that are hard to express using classes. So it is very nice to know there are optional ways of doing the same thing,

Comment: Yes this is simple and nice solution but in my case the all this is already happening inside a .change function so if i add another .change then user has to click twice. :|

Comment: I cannot fully understand what is the scenario. Can you create a snippet to recreate the scenario of the problem?